# How to code a macro to copy and paste data every weekday, but on monday pastes weekend data?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a query that updates everyday in my spreadsheet. It will update the last 4 days so the range "A2:G17" is fixed.

Im trying to copy this range and paste it in a dataset. I would run this sheet every weekday but would not on the weekend. How would i code a way for the macro to paste into a dataset daily, but on monday it pastes saturday and sunday's data when i wasnt using the sheet?

Below is the code I have that copies the last day and pastes in the last row not used. Could someone explain how i would alter it where it could take care of weekends automatically?

```
Dim wsMain As Worksheet, wsHistory As Worksheet

Dim NextRow As Long

Dim rLastRow As Range

' Set Variables

Set wsMain = Sheets("Daily Usage Query")

Set wsHistory = Sheets("AllData")

' Any time the main worksheet B21 changes

If Target.Address = "$B$21" Then

' Get the next row on history sheet

NextRow = wsHistory.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Copy values

wsMain.Range("A14:G17").Copy Destination:=wsHistory.Range("A" & NextRow)

End If
```

Comment: write a loop for the Monday task and have an if() to select either Monday or other based on the day it is run.

Comment: We have no idea what your data looks like, so it's difficult to say how you'd modify this...  Is this code in an event handler?

Comment: Thanks solar Mike, ur comment got my head thinking and i got it to work. Only problem is how do i take holidays into consideration.. i feel like there is a more reliable way of doing this rather than what i was thinking.

Comment: Check out the series of workdays functions, networkdays.intl() is one that takes holiday info but it is not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks solar Mike, ur comment got my head thinking and i got it to work. Only problem is how do i take holidays into consideration.. i feel like there is a more reliable way of doing this rather than what i was thinking.



Dim wsMain As Worksheet, wsHistory As Worksheet
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim rLastRow As Range
Dim K As String

' Current Date
K = Date

D = Weekday(K)

' Change these to your worksheet names
Set wsMain = Sheets("Daily Usage Query")
Set wsHistory = Sheets("AllData")

If D = 2 Then
    ' Any time the main worksheet B2 changes
    If Target.Address = "$B$21" Then

        ' Get the next row on history sheet
        NextRow = wsHistory.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ' Copy values
        wsMain.Range("A6:G17").Copy Destination:=wsHistory.Range("A" & NextRow)
        
        End If
Else
    If Target.Address = "$B$21" Then

        ' Get the next row on history sheet
        NextRow = wsHistory.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ' Copy values
        wsMain.Range("A14:G17").Copy Destination:=wsHistory.Range("A" & NextRow)
        
        End If

End If
```

End Sub